# How can jQuery be used to change HTML pages

Tags: jquery

I'm curious, is there a way jQuery can be used to switch from one html page to another, for example switching from home page to page1 after a few seconds.

```
      <html>
  <head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>

  </div>
  </body>
  </html>



    <html>
  <head>
  <title>Page1</title>
  </head>

  <body>

  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: FYI - what you're talking about is a "redirect"

Comment: no, jquery can't do it. Javascript or html can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code...

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    window.location.replace("http://www.I.Will.Spam.You.com/");
}, 1000); //1 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code example it appears that you want to change page content, not redirect to a new URL. If a redirect isn't what you're after, you can easily change content with jQuery (though not entire pages without ajax).

```
<div id="one">
...
</div>

<div id="two" style="display: none;">
...
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#one, #two').toggle();
        $(document).attr('title', 'Page 1');
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### What you require might be a redirect to a new page

```
success: function () {
  document.location.href='/newpage/'; // jquery
}

window.location.replace('/somepage/within/thewebsite'); // js
```

And yes, there are many ways of doing this if you want to stay on the page and just change the content, I will show you some examples of them

### Using Ajax

You can use ajax, to change the content of the web page like this:

```
function redit() { 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'url_of/page_to/load.html', // send ajax request
    success: function (date) {       // if data is recieved,
      $('body').html(data);          // write it in the body tag..
    }
  })
}

setInterval(redit(), 1000); // after one second (1000ms = 1s)
```

You can learn this here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

### Using Load

By this method, all you need is a link to the page, and use that to load its content (text)

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

Learn it here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation.